# Rails migration error 'wrong number of arguments'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, trace, rspec-rails

I'm unable to migrate, getting this error:

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> Caused by:
> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
> /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/db/migrate/20130614160852_add_first_name_last_name_user_type_values_to_user.rb:3  > :in `change'   /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/lib/tasks/multitenant.rake:32:in` block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/lib/tasks/multitenant.rake:18:in `block in migrate_each'   /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/app/services/tenant.rb:132:in` with_public'
> /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/lib/tasks/multitenant.rake:16:in `migrate_each'   /home/ciaranmurphy/cashanalytics/lib/tasks/multitenant.rake:31:in` block in <top (required)>'
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I tried migration and trace, nothing fixed it

Comment: Your error is telling you the file and line the error is in but you're not showing us that file

Comment: Upload `cashanalytics/db/migrate/20130614160852_add_first_name_last_name_user_type_values_to_user.rb` please